# Replacing a substring with a link on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

In my app, I store emails.

I want to parse those emails for email addresses in the text, on the fly and replace them with a link (so that we send the email through the app).

e.g. 
@email.body = "Hi Tom, Drop me a line at jerry@cheese.com."

I want some sort of helper that will translate that on the fly to:

@email.sanitized_body

> "Hi Tom, Drop me a line at #{link_to "Email", email_send_email_path("jerry@cheese.com")}."

I've been around a few circles. 
e.g. in a model
    Class Email

```
def sanitized_body
  text = self.body
  emails = text.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)
  emails.each do |email|
    text.gsub!("jerry@cheese.com", helper.link_to("email",    "http://www.google.com"))
  end
  text
end
```

I'm sure there's a sensible way of doing this, probably with a helper but can't quite work it out...

```
module EmailsHelper

def sanitized_body(email_body)
  text = email_body
  emails = text.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)
  emails.each do |email|
    text.gsub!("jerry@cheese.com", "#{link_to("email", "http://www.google.com")}")
  end
  text
end

end
```

Gets me almost there. But the text comes out as text in the string when displayed.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) for your text to be rendered as HTML code instead of a simple string.

```
module EmailsHelper

  def sanitized_body(email_body)
    text = email_body
    emails = text.scan(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)
    replace_text = "You text %s" % helper.link_to("email", "http://www.google.com")
    emails.each do |email|
      text.gsub!("jerry@cheese.com", replace_text.html_safe)
    end
    text
  end

end
```